# How to show error message if user not select any checkbox using angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have added based on checkbox selection that dropdown will change. If the user does not select any checkbox, I need to show one error message. How can I do that?

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", MyCtrlFun);
MyCtrlFun.$inject = ['$scope', '$filter', '$timeout','$http'];
function MyCtrlFun($scope, $filter, $timeout,$http) {

//****** Selected List****
$scope.selectedlist = ["Lumia 735 TS", "Lumia 510"];

$scope.checkbox_model = [];
$scope.checkbox_list = [];

$scope.offers = [];
$scope.phones = [];

$scope.submitModel = [];
var submodel = [];
var models = {};
var brandname = {};
$scope.finalOutput = {
  city:null,
    Storename : null,
    Offerid : null,
    Offer_price : null,
    Total_price : null,
    Sub_Total_price : null,
    Categories : []
}

 
$scope.finalOutput_withNullFilter = {};

 
  
$scope.checkItems = function(){
  $scope.checkbox_list = [];
  $scope.selectedlist = new Array();
  
  for(var item in $scope.checkbox_model){
  if($scope.checkbox_model[item].isChecked)
    {
      $scope.selectedlist.push($scope.checkbox_model[item].name);
      $scope.checkbox_list.push($scope.checkbox_model[item]);
    }
    
    
  }
  $scope.checkbox_list.push({offer_id : $scope.selected_offer_id});
  //alert(Storename)
  /*var m = priceChangeToOffer($scope.selected_offer_id);
  
  if(!isNaN(m)){
   $scope.total_price =$scope.total_price-parseInt(m);
    }*/
  $scope.checkbox_list.push({sub_total : $scope.sub_total});
  checkWithSeletedModel();
  
  $scope.finalOutput.city=$scope.phones[0].city;
  
  $scope.finalOutput_withNullFilter = $scope.finalOutput;
  
  if($scope.finalOutput.Storename==null)
  {
   $scope.finalOutput.Storename = $scope.phones[0].Storename;
  }
  
  if($scope.selected_item==null)
  {
      delete $scope.finalOutput.Offerid;
  }
  else{
      $scope.finalOutput.Offerid = $scope.selected_item;
  }
  
  if($scope.Offer_price==0)
  {
    delete $scope.finalOutput.Offer_price;  
  }
  else{
      $scope.finalOutput.Offer_price = $scope.Offer_price;
  }
  
  $scope.finalOutput.Sub_Total_price = $scope.sub_total;
  $scope.finalOutput.Total_price= $scope.total_price;
  
  if($scope.finalOutput.Total_price<=0 && $scope.finalOutput.Sub_Total_price==0){
      alert("please select at least one item");
  }
  else{
    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.finalOutput));
 }
  
  //****** redefine finalOutput after Submit data to server
  $scope.finalOutput = {
      city:null,
      Storename : null,
      Offerid : null,
      Offer_price : null,
      Total_price : null,
      Sub_Total_price : null,
      Categories : []
  }
}

$scope.selectedbrand = 'Nokia';
$scope.submodel ='Lumia';
$scope.phones = [{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56a9c44f40d0275643cfc04e"
    },
    "default": [],
    "Categories": [
        {
            "models": [
                {
                    "submodel": [
                        {
                            "price": "Not available",
                            "name": "Lumia 735 TS"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "8100",
                            "name": "Lumia 510"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "9900",
                            "name": "Lumia 830"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Lumia"
                },
                {
                    "submodel": [
                        {
                            "price": "10000",
                            "name": "Asha 230"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "11999",
                            "name": "Asha Asn01"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Asha"
                }
            ],
            "brandname": "Nokia",
            "id": "986745"
        },
        {
            "models": [
                {
                    "submodel": [
                        {
                            "price": "5000",
                            "name": "Trend 840"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "6999",
                            "name": "A5"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Galaxy"
                },
                {
                    "submodel": [
                        {
                            "price": "12000",
                            "name": "Asha 230"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Asha"
                }
            ],
            "brandname": "Samsung",
            "id": "144745"
        }
    ],
    "Storename": "Zig Zag Mobiles",
 "Shopid":"asdef1234",
  "city":"bengaluru",
    "__v": 0
}
 
];

$scope.offers = [
 {
  id: "as23456",
  "Storename": "Zig Zag Mobiles",
  "Shopid":"asdef1234",
        "Offer_message":"1000rs off",
  "Categories": [
        {
            "models": [
                {
                    "submodel": [
                        {
                            "price": "1000",
                            "name": "Lumia 735 TS"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Lumia"
                }
            ],
            "brandname": "Nokia",
            "id": "986745"
        }
    ],  
      
    },{
  id: "de34575",
        "Storename": "Zig Zag Mobiles",
  "Shopid":"asdef1234",
        "Offer_message":"500rs off",
  "Categories": [
        {
            "models": [
                {
                    "submodel": [
                        {
                            "price": "500",
                            "name": "Lumia 830"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Lumia"
                }
            ],
            "brandname": "Nokia",
            "id": "345645"
        }
    ],         
      
    },
 {
  id: "ert25675",
        "Storename": "Zig Zag Mobiles",
  "Shopid":"asdef1234",
        "Offer_message":"100 Flat",
  "Categories": [
        {
            "models": [
                {
                    "submodel": [
                        {
                            "price": "100",
                            "name": "Asha 230"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Asha"
                }
            ],
            "brandname": "Samsung",
            "id": "345645"
        }
    ],         
      
    }
];
        
   /*$http.get('http://19.168.1.4/shop1/').success(function(data, status, response) 
        {
  $scope.phones =data;
  });*/
//----------------------------Our Shop Offers----------------------------------------
/*$http.get('http://19.168.1.4/shop1/').success(function(response,data) 
{
    $scope.phones =[data];
    checkWithSeletedModel();
}).error(function(error, status){
    alert("got error"+status);
});
  
$http.get('http://19.168.1.4/offers/').success(function(data, status, response) 
{
    $scope.offers =data;
}).error(function(error, status){
    alert("got error"+status);
});*/

  $scope.offerSelectedList = [];
  $scope.total_price = 0, $scope.sub_total=0, $scope.Offer_price=0, $scope.selected_item=null;
  $scope.changeItemStateFun = function(checkbox_value){
      $scope.selected_item=null;
      $scope.Offer_price=0;
      
    $timeout(function(){
        if(checkbox_value.isChecked){

          if(!isNaN(checkbox_value.price)){
            $scope.total_price =$scope.total_price+parseInt(checkbox_value.price);
            }

          var checked_offer = getOffer([checkbox_value]);

                    if(checked_offer!=false){
              $scope.offerSelectedList.push(checked_offer);
              //alert(checked_offer.Categories[0].models[0].submodel[0].name);
            }
        }else{
          if(!isNaN(checkbox_value.price)){
                    $scope.total_price = $scope.total_price-parseInt(checkbox_value.price);
            }

            var checked_offer = getOffer([checkbox_value]);
          if(checked_offer!=false){
              var tempOfferList = [];
              for(var i in $scope.offerSelectedList){
                 if($scope.offerSelectedList[i].id!=checked_offer.id){
                    tempOfferList.push($scope.offerSelectedList[i]);
                 }
              }
              $scope.offerSelectedList = tempOfferList;
            }
        }

        if($scope.offerSelectedList.length==0){
            $scope.Offer_price = 0;
            $scope.sub_total = $scope.total_price;
        }
        else{
          $scope.Offer_price = $scope.offerSelectedList[0].Categories[0].models[0].submodel[0].price;
          $scope.sub_total = $scope.total_price-$scope.Offer_price;
          $scope.selected_item = $scope.offerSelectedList[0].id;
        }

        $scope.finalOutput.Total_price = $scope.total_price;
    });
  }
  
  $scope.selected_offer_id = null;
  $scope.submit_offer = {};
  $scope.offerSeleted = function(offer){
      
      $scope.selected_item = null;
      $scope.Offer_price =0;
      
    $scope.selected_offer_id = offer;
    var m = priceChangeToOffer($scope.selected_offer_id);
    
    if(!isNaN(m.Offer_price)){
        
      $scope.Offer_price = parseInt(m.Offer_price);
      $scope.sub_total =$scope.total_price-$scope.Offer_price;
      }
      
    $scope.selected_item=m.Offerid;
    $scope.Offer_price = m.Offer_price;
    
    $scope.finalOutput.Storename = m.Storename;
    $scope.finalOutput.Offerid = m.Offerid;
    $scope.finalOutput.Offer_price = m.Offer_price;
    $scope.finalOutput.Total_price = $scope.total_price;
    $scope.finalOutput.Sub_Total_price = $scope.sub_total;
    
  }
  
  function getOffer(checkedItem){
   for(var i=0; i<checkedItem.length; i++){
    
     for(var j=0; j<$scope.offers.length; j++){
       for(var k=0;k<$scope.offers[j].Categories.length; k++){
         for(var m=0; m<$scope.offers[j].Categories[k].models.length; m++){
           for(var n=0; n<$scope.offers[j].Categories[k].models[m].submodel.length; n++){
               if($scope.offers[j].Categories[k].models[m].submodel[n].name==checkedItem[i].name){
                  
                    return $scope.offers[j];
                    }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    return false;
  }
 //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //delete below line
  checkWithSeletedModel();
  function checkWithSeletedModel(){
  
  $scope.finalOutput.Categories = [];
  $scope.submitModel = [];
 submodel = [];
 models = {};
 brandname = {};
  $scope.offerSelectedList = [];
  $scope.total_price = 0;
  
  $scope.checkbox_model = [];

  for(var i=0; i<$scope.phones.length; i++){
   for(var j=0; j<$scope.phones[i].Categories.length; j++){
     
      if($scope.phones[i].Categories[j].brandname==$scope.selectedbrand){
      
      brandname = {
         id : $scope.phones[i].Categories[j].id,
          brandname : $scope.phones[i].Categories[j].brandname,
          models : []
        };
       models = {};
      for(var k=0; k<$scope.phones[i].Categories[j].models.length; k++){
         if($scope.phones[i].Categories[j].models[k].name==$scope.submodel){    
       models = {
           name : $scope.phones[i].Categories[j].models[k].name,
            submodel : []
          }
          
        for(var m=0; m<$scope.phones[i].Categories[j].models[k].submodel.length; m++){

    var verifyIsCheck = false;
    if($scope.selectedlist.length>0){
    verifyIsCheck=verifyIsChecked($scope.phones[i].Categories[j].models[k].submodel[m].name);
     }
         if(verifyIsCheck==true){
           models.submodel.push({name : $scope.phones[i].Categories[j].models[k].submodel[m].name, price:($scope.phones[i].Categories[j].models[k].submodel[m].price=='Not available'?null:$scope.phones[i].Categories[j].models[k].submodel[m].price)});
            //models.submodel
         }
         
         var obj1 = {isChecked :verifyIsCheck, name : $scope.phones[i].Categories[j].models[k].submodel[m].name, price:$scope.phones[i].Categories[j].models[k].submodel[m].price};
            
           //$scope.changeItemStateFun(obj1);
            var checkedOffer = getOffer([obj1]);
            if(checkedOffer!=false && verifyIsCheck==true){
             $scope.offerSelectedList.push(checkedOffer); 
              
            }
            if(verifyIsCheck==true && !isNaN(obj1.price)){
             $scope.total_price = $scope.total_price+parseInt(obj1.price);
              }
            
            $scope.checkbox_model.push(obj1);
          }
          }
      }
      brandname.models.push(models);
      $scope.submitModel.push(brandname);
      }
   }
}

$scope.finalOutput.Categories.push($scope.submitModel);
}


  function verifyIsChecked(submodel_name){
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.selectedlist.length; i++){
   if($scope.selectedlist[i]==submodel_name){
      
         return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  
  //********** For total sum checked model and change according to offer
 function priceChangeToOffer(offer_id){
 
    for(var j=0; j<$scope.offers.length; j++){
    
      if(offer_id!=$scope.offers[j].id)
         continue;
       
        for(var k=0;k<$scope.offers[j].Categories.length; k++){
         for(var m=0; m<$scope.offers[j].Categories[k].models.length; m++){
           for(var n=0; n<$scope.offers[j].Categories[k].models[m].submodel.length; n++){
             var offer_obj = {
               Storename : $scope.offers[j].Storename,
        Offerid :  $scope.offers[j].id,
        Offer_price : $scope.offers[j].Categories[k].models[m].submodel[0].price
              };
              return offer_obj;
            }
          }
        }
      }
 }  

$scope.sub_total = $scope.total_price;
$scope.finalOutput.Total_price = $scope.total_price;
$scope.finalOutput.Sub_Total_price = $scope.sub_total;

}


myApp.filter("removespace", function(){
   return function(input){
     return input.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, "_")
   }
});
//]]> 
//]]> 

//]]>
```

```html
<div  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

        <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in phones">
          <div ng-repeat="cat in item.Categories" ng-show="cat.brandname==selectedbrand">
            <h2><b>{{ cat.brandname }}</b></h2>
              <div ng-repeat="models in cat.models" ng-show="models.name==submodel">
                <h3>
                  <b>{{models.name}}</b>
                </h3>
                <div ng-repeat="submodels in models.submodel">
                  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox_model[$index].isChecked" ng-change="changeItemStateFun(checkbox_model[$index])"/>{{ submodels.name }}

                </div><br/><br/>
                <div><b>Total Price : {{total_price}}</b><br/></div>
                <div ng-show="Offer_price!=0"><b>Offer Price : {{Offer_price}}</b></div>
                <div><b>Sub Total = {{sub_total}}</b><br/></div>
                <select ng-show="offerSelectedList.length>0" ng-model="selected_item" ng-options="offer.id as offer.Offer_message for offer in offerSelectedList" ng-change="offerSeleted(selected_item)">
                  <option>select offer</option>
                </select>
                
                <!--<select  ng-show="offerSelectedList.length>0" ng-model="selected_item" ng-change="offerSeleted(selected_item)">
                    <option ng-repeat="offer in offerSelectedList" value="{{offer.id}}">{{offer.Offer_message}} {{offer.id}}</option>
                </select>-->


              </div>
          </div>



      <button ng-click="checkItems()">Do</button>
      </div>  
      </div>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/23734/)

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/23736/) ?

Comment: no one alert should come it says pls select atleast one

Comment: [Updated Link](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/23738/)

Comment: thanks its working i need one more help

Comment: Posting this as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly simple. I've gone ahead and used a flag variable `$scope.flag` which is set to true by default in your `checkItems()` function.

```
$scope.flag=true;
```

In the for loop that checks for checked boxes, I set the value of flag to false if it enters the if section

```
if($scope.checkbox_model[item].isChecked)
    {
    $scope.flag=false;
            $scope.selectedlist.push($scope.checkbox_model[item].name);
            $scope.checkbox_list.push($scope.checkbox_model[item]);
    }
```

After the loop ends, I check for a false flag and set an alert. I'm returning false because I'm not sure what is the action after the button is click.Remove it if you feel the need.

```
 if($scope.flag==true){alert("Select one");return false;}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/23738/)

Comment: i need one more help

Comment: Yes, go ahead and tell me.

Comment: how can i reduce code for above task.if possible pls reduce my code

Comment: I'll have a look and post an update if something works out, also try posting it [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's a lot of code, so your best bet is the code review stack exchange. Also, I've updated the answer with a return false, which you could keep or remove depending upon your requirement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103272/discussion-between-komal-and-satej-s).